# Is there a way to syncronize my iPod classic with iTunes OTA?

Tags: itunes, wireless-networking, sync, ipod

Is there a way to synchronize my iPod Classic with iTunes over the air?
I'm too lazy to connect through USB all the time..

Yes, the iPod classic has no WiFi adapter, but maybe some tweakers have a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

I understand that there isn't anything that would allow this short of creating a paired set of a hardware board and a software application that would trick the iPod into thinking it had a native USB connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/593017-REG/Audioengine_AW2_AW2_Premium_Wireless_Adapter.html), it has all the disadvantages mentioned, but you can do what you want, plus connect vía AirTunes to any WiFi adapters from Apple, and through this, to any amplifier.

Comment: Does this even work on an iPod classic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have found a solution, but bluetooth only. I am still looking for wifi options, so if you have one, please respond. 
For bluetooth: Sonos has built a wireles dock (WD100), so you can charge your ipod classic/ mini/ nano/ iphone etc and send the music wireless by bluetooth to your audio system with bluetooth receiver. 
 Of course, this is not the cheapest option, because you need and the sonos bluetooth dock and a bluetooth receiver for your audio system, but it does work. 
Probably an (originial apple) audio dock directly connected to your audio receiver will be much cheaper.

Answer (score -1):

You probably wouldn't be that happy with it anyway. A key factor of the original 2001 iPod's success was that it could sync at a decent rate because it used 400mbps FireWire, whereas all other players took for...ev...er to sync because they used USB 1.1 at 12mbps (USB 2.0 hi-speed at 480mbps wasn't out yet).

Even if you had the latest bleeding-edge 3-stream (3x3) 802.11n gear at a nominal rate of 450mbps, you'd only get a little over 200mbps of throughput because of the typical overhead of 802.11, which means you'd only be half as fast as an iPod from almost a decade ago. Plus such an adapter would probably cost well over $100, it would be bulky, it would eat through batteries, and you'd have to buy an expensive new 3-stream wireless base station to go with it.

A more realistic scenario is that you have 802.11g at a nominal 54mbps of which you'd be lucky to see fully 20mbps of throughput in ideal conditions.  Typical would be perhaps 15mbps.

If you're like me and wish your iPod could sync *even faster* than it does today on USB 2.0 hi-speed at 480mbps (where you actually see throughput close to 400mbps), the idea of having sync take  **25 times** as long just for the convenience of wireless doesn't sound all that appealing.

Wireless USB would have done what you wanted because it was apparently capable of 480mbps at a few meters, but it seems it never really got off the ground. Products apparently first appeared in 2007, but there are still very few products available. Even if someone had made a WUSB dongle or sled that snapped onto an iPod classic to enable it to sync over WUSB, it would've cost ~$150 and been bulky and required its own batteries.  You probably wouldn't want to keep such a device snapped onto your iPod, so you would have to remember to find it and snap into it so your iPod could sync, which doesn't make it that much more convenient than docking the traditional way.

I think the only way we'll ever see wireless syncing on iPods is if Apple makes a way for iPhone and iPod touch syncing to happen incrementally in the background (leaving the device free to be used in the mean time) using the built-in WiFi in those devices. That's the only way I can see it having a good enough user experience to be worth it. And even that would have fairly significant battery life impact.